# Can Google glog notify the application of full disk?

Tags: c++, glog

I would like to be able to respond (possibly simply by dying) to the glog being unable to log to disk due to a full disk. Is there any way to convince glog to report this condition to the program using it?

Comment: You can try installing your failure signal handler to see if it can catch it. See [here](https://google-glog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/glog.html)

Comment: @simon Is there a signal handler for full disk? All I see in that link is the "Failure Signal Handler" which, since glog doesn't seem to think of full disk as an error, I'm not thinking would fire.

Comment: Have you try it? What is the symptom you observed when glog being unable to log to disk due to a disk full?

Comment: I haven't experienced a full disk with the signal handle registered, but the typical response by glog appears to be to hold the logs for writing once disk space becomes available.

Comment: If you don't like that behavior, you can use the `google::SetStopLoggingIfFullDisk(const bool a_bValue)` to change the disk full behavior.

Comment: @simon I believe the flag you suggested actually causes the above behavior. You may simply lose messages without the flag set.

Comment: Yes, it is two side of the flag value, you can either turn it on or off. I think the default is on. If you turn it off, you might be able to catch the disk full in Failure signal handler.

Comment: @simon regardless of how the flag is set, google glog does not either throw an exception or provide any data through the failure signal handler.